# Firebase deploy error: Error: Task 36af5812590007491b4e76c59df3b5a9afb37586b8a3eab39bb16d14cacf1c64 failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts

Tags: javascript

[image]

I am facing this error when deploy in Firebase you have any idea I tried Google

Comment: Did you try to add the `--debug` option? What do you get as an output? Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911225/firebase-hosting-deployment-failing) can help you.

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699826/firebase-hosting-deploy-error-task-5fc-failed-retries-exhausted-after-6-att

Comment: Did you try to empty your .firebase folder?

Comment: not worked i tried a lot